# SproutCore newbie confusion

Tags: web-applications, sproutcore

I installed SproutCore on my Linux box using instructions shown here http://www.sproutcore.com/install_linux/ .Now when I create an app using `sc-init` I got files which are different from the files mentioned in this official tutorial :  http://guides.sproutcore.com/getting_started.html . So what is outdated: the version of SproutCore I'm using or the tutorial?

My todo sproutcore app folder structure:

```
-resources
  loading.html
  main_page.js
Buildfile
core.js
main.js
theme.js
```

Am I running the latest SproutCore in the market?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what is outdated the version of sproutcore i'm using or the
>   tutorial?

Neither. If you followed the instructions provided then you installed SproutCore 1.6, which is the latest **stable** release. As for your directory structure, it differs from the tutorial because you failed to add `--template`; see below.

```
sc-init MyAppName --template
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work right. Like Dan said, you only forgot the `--template` parameter, which creates a bigger folder structure. 
But you do not need to use `--template`
You can add a "resources" folder with subfolders "stylesheets" or "images" on your own.

And once you use the console to create views, models or controlers, more folders get added automatically and the folder structure soon will make more sense.

If you want to get more familiar with how the folder structure and SC App creation and class generation are working, check out the build tools: 
[sc-gen](http://wiki.sproutcore.com/w/page/12412837/Abbot%20Spec%20sc-gen) and [build tools](http://wiki.sproutcore.com/w/page/12412862/BuildTools-About%20Build%20Tools)